# CSS framework for printing A4 format

Tags: css, frameworks, printing

I'm trying to layout printable magazines on a web application, using XHTML and CSS. It's not easy !
I would like to know if a CSS framework could help me handling page format, positioning and physical units like millimeters.

Some details I forgot. The magazines are not printed directly by the user with a print.css. The application generates a PDF version which is then printed.

Answer (score -2):

What are you using as a PDF generator ? From my experience, not all PDF generators are predictable in the way they render CSS. The best I've found was Prince XML, but it's commercial license for a server cost 3600 USD, which depending on what you're going to use it for could be quite expensive.

Anyway, it should be fairly easy to adapt a framework like Blueprint to use metric units instead of pixels. Print frameworks I've checked don't seem to provide what screen CSS frameworks do.